# laravel grouping by multiple columns

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

Im using laravel 5.2 and I want to group a table based on the value of two columns (configuration and type). So basically if two or more rows in the table have the same configuration and type they will be grouped.
I've tried querying like this and its not working:

```
 $groups = Model::where('active', 1)->get()->groupBy('type_id', 'configuration_id');
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I think I'm using the wrong query. What I want to do is get the rows that have the same values in these two columns and have them grouped. Apparently group by is used to aggregate things e.g if I want a sum or something.

EDIT 2: Actually the groupby here I'm using is not part of the query it is a helper function provided by laravel to use on collections see this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-groupby) Does anyone know if it groups by two feilds??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I've figured it out.
The groupBy method I'm using is not a query it is a laravel function that groups collections by a certain field. You can see the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_groupBy). So the workaround was to do the grouping twice like this.

```
$groups = Model::where('active', 1)->get()->groupBy('type_id');

foreach ($groups as $group) {
    $grouped[] =  $group->groupBy('configuration_id');
}
```

Comment: thanks, man! this must have saved me many days!

Answer (score 4):

Pass Columns names in array form this is working for me

```
$groups = Model::where('active', 1)->groupBy(['type_id', 'configuration_id','etc']);
```

Comment: Tested in laravel 5.6 Need to have array . Thanks for pointing this out . Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
 $groups = Model::where('active', 1)->groupBy('type_id', 'configuration_id')->get();
```

Comment: This one works but it gets the first one of each group. Any idea why?

Comment: No idea. May be we will refer the document and so we will get any idea about this.

Comment: @user3552551 put groupBy after get() and it will work as you expect. Don't ask me why I have no idea :)

Comment: Probably it because before get - it works for grouping on database side - and first result - it works as expected. After `get` - you're grouping collection already, on php-side.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$groups = Model::where('active', 1)->groupBy('type_id', 'configuration_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$groups = Model::where('active', 1)->groupBy('type_id', 'configuration_id')->get(['type_id', 'configuration_id']);
```

Comment: Okay... it will group the columns and you can get some specific fields by get function...